# Insert javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, insert

i have this code:

```
 <a href='google.com'  title=' '> <script>exam='y';</script> </a>
```

I want to add this script `<script>exam='y';</script>` inside title tag, like this:

```
 <a href='google.com'  title=' <script>exam='y';</script> '> <script>exam='y';</script> </a>
```

But it does not work. Hope for your helps.

Comment: What are you expecting, what are you seeing? The first obvious answer would be to use `"` quotes for the `title` string

Comment: I think you want to change the title of your page dynamically...
Do specify EXACTLY what it is that you want to do...

Answer (score 2):

Put your javascript separate in script tag and then point to your element attribute to set it

```
<a id="myId" href='google.com' title=''> my link </a>


window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("myId").setAttribute("title", "some title");
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/rHddx/1/

If you set your title dynamically, you do not need the attribute in the tag. It will be set by javascript, as thfollowing fiddle will show you.

http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/rHddx/2/

Comment: If the script is placed after the element it looks for, you don't need to wait for the page load.

Comment: Also, it must be noted that there can only be one `onload` handler defined this way. If you need two of them, use `addEventListener` (+`attachHandler` if you need to support IE<9 - or use jQuery).

Comment: @Jan - yes, correct. As soon as an element is created in the DOM, you can manipulate it.

Comment: @Jan - Again, you are correct. That situation will however be scarce. Personally I would prefer just one as a constructor. That is more a matter of preference. Thanks for adding some thoughts.